# Testing Optimistic update in react query

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

I am trying to write the test case for an optimistic update in react query. But it's not working. Here is the code that I wrote to test it. Hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance. When I just write the onSuccess and leave an optimistic update, it works fine but here it's not working. And how can we mock the getQueryData and setQueryData here?

```
import { act, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import axios from "axios";
import { createWrapper } from "../../test-utils";
import { useAddColorHook, useFetchColorHook } from "./usePaginationReactQuery";
jest.mock("axios");

describe('Testing custom hooks of react query', () => {

    it('Should add a new color', async () => {
        axios.post.mockReturnValue({data: [{label: 'Grey', id: 23}]})
        const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useAddColorHook(1), { wrapper: createWrapper() });
        await act(() => {
            result.current.mutate({ label: 'Grey' })
        })
        await waitFor(() => result.current.isSuccess);
    })
})

export const createTestQueryClient = () =>
  new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        retry: false,
        cacheTime: Infinity,
      },
    },
    logger: {
      log: console.log,
      warn: console.warn,
      error: () => {},
    }
  });

export function createWrapper() {
  const testQueryClient = createTestQueryClient();
  return ({ children }) => (
    <QueryClientProvider client={testQueryClient}>
      {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

```
export const useAddColorHook = (page) => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    return useMutation(addColor, {
        // onSuccess: () => {
        //     queryClient.invalidateQueries(['colors', page])
        // }
        onMutate: async color => {
            // newHero refers to the argument being passed to the mutate function
            await queryClient.cancelQueries(['colors', page])
            const previousHeroData = queryClient.getQueryData(['colors', page])
            queryClient.setQueryData(['colors', page], (oldQueryData) => {
                return {
                    ...oldQueryData,
                    data: [...oldQueryData.data, { id: oldQueryData?.data?.length + 1, ...color }]
                }
            })
            return { previousHeroData }
        },
        onSuccess: (response, variables, context) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(['colors', page], (oldQueryData) => {
                console.log(oldQueryData, 'oldQueryData', response, 'response', variables, 'var', context, 'context', 7984)
                return {
                    ...oldQueryData,
                    data: oldQueryData.data.map(data => data.label === variables.label ? response.data : data)
                }
            })
        },
        onError: (_err, _newTodo, context) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(['colors', page], context.previousHeroData)
        },
        onSettled: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries(['colors', page])
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It's getting to onError due to this line 
const previousColorData = queryClient.getQueryData(['colors', page])
Maybe i need to mock this getQueryData but don't know how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you are getting actually shows a bug in the way you've implemented the optimistic update:

```
queryClient.setQueryData(['colors', page], (oldQueryData) => {
  return {
    ...oldQueryData,
    data: [...oldQueryData.data, { id: oldQueryData?.data?.length + 1, ...color }]
  }
})
```

what if there is no entry in the query cache that matches this query key? `oldQueryData` will be `undefined`, but you're not guarding against that, you are spreading `...oldQueryData.data` and this will error out at runtime.

This is what happens in your test because you start with a fresh query cache for every test.

An easy way out would be, since you have `previousHeroData` already:

```
const previousHeroData = queryClient.getQueryData(['colors', page])
if (previousHeroData) {
  queryClient.setQueryData(['colors', page], {
    ...previousHeroData,
    data: [...previousHeroData.data, { id: previousHeroData.data.length + 1, ...color }]
  }
}
```

If you are using TanStack/query v4, you can also return *undefined* from the updater function. This doesn't work in v3 though:

```
queryClient.setQueryData(['colors', page], (oldQueryData) => {
    return oldQueryData ? {
        ...oldQueryData,
        data: [...oldQueryData.data, { id: oldQueryData?.data?.length + 1, ...color }]
    } : undefined
})
```

This doesn't perform an optimistic update then though. If you know how to create a valid cache entry from `undefined` previous data, you can of course also do that.

Comment: Thank you for the time you dedicated here, but I have one more question. Is there a way that we can store some cached value for this respective key and get the previousHeroData and oldQueryData.

Comment: in your test, you can set `queryClient.setQueryData(key, data)` to put data in the cache.